# SUMIF not working properly with criteria in row and values in column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, sumifs

I needed to build a SUMIF formula to sum a VERTICAL sum_range with a HORIZONTAL range of criteria.

Utilizing the the SUMIF function in the format `=SUMIF(A2:D2,"there",E1:E4)` made me expect that excel would sum the values in the sum_range vector if the criteria in the A2:D2 vector were met (="there"). But for some reason the formula is going horizontally from E1 (see image bellow), and disregarding E2 to E4.

Does anybody know a way to solve this? Or an alternative formula?

[image: print from an excel example file]

Comment: That's because SUMIF is designed so that the actual range defined by Excel for the sum range starts with the upper left cell of the specified range, but corresponds to the same size as the criteria range.  Therefore, since the size of the criteria range is 1 Row by 4 Columns, the sum range will also be 1 Row by 4 Columns, starting at E1, hence E1:H1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hack it by transforming the `A2:D2` range into a set of 0s and 1s and then replacing `SUMIF` with `SUMPRODUCT` as below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(A2:D2="there",1,0),TRANSPOSE(E1:E4))
```

Remember to enter this formula with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` as the `TRANSPOSE` function is an array call within `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: It works without CSE for me in Excel 365! It worked after dropping `IF` function like `=SUMPRODUCT((A2:D2="there")*TRANSPOSE(E1:E4))`. It works +1!

Comment: It worked for me with and without IF in Excel 365! Thank you very much!